# Why when I increase the standard deviation in the pdf function the graph looks squeezed instead of more dispersed?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, density-function, numpy, matplotlib

So what I am doing is this:

```
#Set mean, s as standard deviation, variance, valores (range of values)
valores = np.arange(-10,10,0.01)
mean =2
s = 3
variance = np.square(s)

# Calculate the pdf
pdf = np.exp(-np.square(valores-mean)/2*variance)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance))


# Plot it:
plt.plot( valores, pdf)
plt.show()
```

If I set `s=3`, my graph is:
[image]

Now if I set `s=6`, my graph is:
[image]

Now, since I increased standard deviation (s from 3 to 6) shouldn't the curve look more "open" or dispersed, not squeezed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a slight parentheses error, your pdf should look like this, with the variance in the denominator of the exponential:

```
pdf = np.exp(-np.square(valores-mean)/(2*variance))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance))
```

Comment: Thanks lennart! What a silly mistake I made